# Creating Dropdown Menu in SharePoint Online - using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, navigation, dropdown

I need some assistance with my PowerShell script. Currently I am able to add a drop down menu to my page, but I am trying to add some subfolders to "Support Center". Also if I wanted to add my drop down to multiple $SiteURL, how do I create it to loop for that?

I have pasted my current code below that adds a drop down in one site URL.

Thank you for any assistance!

```
#Load SharePoint CSOM Assemblies
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\16\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
 
#Add new Link in Top Navigation
Function Add-SPOTopNavigationLink()
{
    Param(
        [String]$SiteURL,
        [parameter(Mandatory=$false)][String]$ParentNodeTitle,
        [String]$Title,
        [String]$URL
    )

    $user = "user"
    $file = "location"
    #Create new credential object and get encrypted password from file 
    $cred = New-Object -TypeName System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList $user, (Get-Content $file | ConvertTo-SecureString)
    $Credentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($Cred.Username, $Cred.Password)
 
    #Setup the context
    $Ctx = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($SiteURL)
    $Ctx.Credentials = $Credentials
 
    #Get the Top Navigation of the web
    $TopNavigationBar = $Ctx.Web.Navigation.TopNavigationBar
    $Ctx.load($TopNavigationBar)
    $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
 
    #Populate New node data
    $NavigationNode = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.NavigationNodeCreationInformation 
    $NavigationNode.Title = $Title
    $NavigationNode.Url = $URL
    $NavigationNode.AsLastNode = $true
 
    #Get the Parent Node
    $ParentNode = $TopNavigationBar | Where-Object {$_.Title -eq $ParentNodeTitle}
     
    #Add New node to the navigation
    If($ParentNode -eq $null)
    {
        #Check if the Link with Title exists already
        $Node = $TopNavigationBar | Where-Object {$_.Title -eq $Title}
        If($Node -eq $Null)
        { 
            #Add Link to Root node of the Navigation
            $Ctx.Load($TopNavigationBar.Add($NavigationNode))
            $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
            Write-Host -f Green "New Link '$Title' Added to the Navigation Root!"
        }
        Else
        {
            Write-Host -f Yellow "Navigation Link '$Title' Already Exists in Root!"
        }
    }
    else
    {
        #Get the Parent Node
        $Ctx.Load($ParentNode)
        $Ctx.Load($ParentNode.Children)
        $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
  
        #Check if the Link with given title exists
        $Node = $ParentNode.Children | Where-Object {$_.Title -eq $Title}
        If($Node -eq $Null)
        { 
            #Add Link to Parent Node
            $Ctx.Load($ParentNode.Children.Add($NavigationNode))
            $Ctx.ExecuteQuery()
            Write-Host -f Green "New Navigation Link '$Title' Added to the Parent '$ParentNodeTitle'!"
        }
        Else
        {
            Write-Host -f Yellow "Navigation Link '$Title' Already Exists in Parnet Node '$ParentNodeTitle'!"
        }
    }
}
  
#Config Parameters
$SiteURL="https://test.sharepoint.com/sites/TestTopLinkBar"
 
#Call the function to Add a New Link in Root of the navigation
Add-SPOTopNavigationLink -SiteURL $SiteURL -Title "TESTING - HOME" -URL "https://yahoo.com"
 
#Call the function to Add a link in "Support Center" node of the navigation
Add-SPOTopNavigationLink -SiteURL $SiteURL -ParentNodeTitle "TESTING - HOME" -Title "Support Center" -URL "https://google.com"
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think for your requirement, you can go with the **megamenu** and **hub site** configuration.

**What is Megamenu Navigation?**

The much-awaited megamenu navigation was recently launched by Microsoft (February & March 2019). It addresses many issues that users have been facing over the last several years in the traditional drop-down navigation approach. One of the major issues of drop-down based navigation is, if the navigation item lists are more, most of the actual content of the site will be hidden or shadowed by the drop-down menu. This is how the user gets frustrated and it leads to poor user adoption to the site. And also in the drop-down-based approach, we cannot have multi-levels of nested items.

**For details refer to the below articles:**

[How to create navigation in modern SharePoint Online](https://global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-online/various-navigation-in-modern-sharepoint-online/)

[How to create hub site in SharePoint Online using PnP PowerShell?](https://global-sharepoint.com/sharepoint-online/hub-sites-in-sharepoint-online-modern-site/)

Answer (score 1):

You can write the sites in a CSV file and import it using

```
Import-CSV -Path C:\SiteURLs.csv
```

And the loop should look like:

```
Import-Csv "C:\SiteURLs.csv" | Foreach-Object {
    Add-SPOTopNavigationLink -SiteURL $_ -Title "Support Center" -URL "/"
    Add-SPOTopNavigationLink -SiteURL $_ -ParentNodeTitle "Support Center" -Title "Application Support" -URL "/"
}
```